# how to extract lines from txt and getting into String array in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, arraylist

I have a text file in this format:

```
Number: xxxxx
Name: xxxxx
Last Name: xxxxxx
```

How can I get each line into a String array or Arraylist?

I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209185/how-to-use-streamreader-to-read-different-lines-of-text-from-txt-file-into-diff) but it's not clear to me.

Why is not duplicate:
If you don't know the function or method, you will never find the "possible duplicated". If you type my common question in Google or Stack search, you will be able to find it. I think here, some people is too paranoid with duplicates.

Comment: Use [*`File.ReadAllLines`*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between File.ReadAllLines() and File.ReadAllText()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965497/what-is-the-difference-between-file-readalllines-and-file-readalltext)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I did it with that, I can't give you any point in comments but you deserve it.
Edit: answering to you possible duplicate... I think I'm not asking the same thing although the answer could be equal... My question is much more common to find what you are looking for in Stack Search

Comment: No need to, I prefer not to answer evident duplicate questions. There is an answer below to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read all lines into a string array use this:

```
Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
```